# Add full Sourcecode in Doxygen search

Tags: search, doxygen

i would like to ask, if it is possible to make the whole sourcecode searchable in doxygens html output ?

I have already found SOURCE_BROWSER and INLINE_SOURCES to display the code, but it is not searchable fulltext via the searchbox...

thanks for your help,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set EXTRACT_ALL = YES

Additionally, Doxygen needs to be able to find all of your sources (see the INPUT and FILE_PATTERNS variables).

Comment: Thank you, but EXTRACT_ALL has no effect on the searchbox.

Comment: I thought that it did affect the search. Are you using SEARCHENGINE =YES and SERVER_BASED_SEARCH = NO?